# How can i get thumbnail of video from Remote URL for android 4.0 and above?

Tags: android, video

Actually, I want to show a thumbnail of video from Video URL and show it in `ImageView` and then on click of `ImageView` the `VideoView` shows video in another activity.
   So ultimately My problem is that, i can't get thumbnail of video from URL.
I have tried a lot but cant get any solution that was worked for me, There is solutions given for only get thumbnail from SD-Card videos and for remote URL there is, I have found some solutions but it isn't working.Below is what I have tried.

```
Bitmap bmThumbnail;
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(VideoURL, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
holder.videoViewFestivities.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Can anybody tell me how to show the thumbnail of a Video which is in a URL?

Thank you.

Comment: You cant do this untill you download the video into your SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Better create a web service for this.  You pass in a Video URL, extract the thumbnail then save it in cache(map url with image) for future calls. look into ffmpeg for the backend solution.